# Running Tensorboard using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, tensorboard

to use Tensorboard I need each time to start cmd and than type the TB command and copy and past the logfiles directory.
I was wondering if this could be avoid by using a batch file that could be generated each time.
To test that I've wrote a small batch file that should start Tensorboard with a specific logdir as followed :

```
Tensorboard  --logdir=D:\Tensorflow\Main\Features_selection\Deep_normed_Feature2
PAUSE
```

The logdir is fine and I can start TB  manually, but when I run the batch file I get a loop effect that I don't how to avoid. here is the command prompt output
[image]

Does anyone here know how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you name the batch file also tensorboard?

Comment: @LotPings you're right the issue thanks for your help! please put this as an answer so that I can close the question !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you name a batch with the same name as the program run
and don't supply an extension,
you create an infinitive loop the batch running itself constantly.

So either choose a different name or explicitly run the program with full path and extension